# What is the difference between IO () and IO?

Tags: haskell

There are two different ways of using `IO` in haskell programs, for example:

```
main :: IO ()
-- and
readLine :: IO Int
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Hint: `()` is the empty tuple, i.e. “no value”.

Comment: oh...that's why there is a space between IO and the ()

Comment: The space between `IO` and `()` doesn't really matter.  The space between `IO` and `Int` does, of course.

Comment: You should read a tutorial on IO. http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IO ()` and `IO Int` are fundamentally very similar.  `Int` and `()` are both types in Haskell.  `()` is special only in the sense that it has only one value ( also denoted by `()` ), so we're never really interested in it.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference is their return value.  `main` returns a value of type `()` and your `readLine` returns an `Int`.  Perhaps this example will help:

```
main = do
    x <- putStrLn "Test"
    print x
```

When you run it, it outputs:

```
>>> main
Test
()
```

The print statement prints a `()` because that is the return value of `putStrLn`:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

The reason you normally don't bind the return value of something like `putStrLn` is that there is no information gained from doing so, since it always returns `()` no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

`IO Int` means: this is an IO action that `return`s an Int.

`IO ()` means: this is an IO action that doesn't return any meaningful result. (like `main`.)

Comment: Technically an `IO ()` does return a result (of type `()`). So I suggest changing the last bit to "doesn't return a *meaningful* result" for pedantry's sake.

Comment: I quote and emphasize: "`IO Int` means: this **function** will perform an action that `return`s an `Int`." No! `IO Int` is not a function! That's in fact the whole point of having `IO` types: that imperative actions are not functions!

Answer (score 1):

`IO ()` is the type of an action that can be executed to extract a value of type `()`. There is only one (non-bottom) value of type `()`, which is also spelled `()` (you tell them apart by knowing whether you're looking at a type expression or a value expression, just as names starting with an uppercase letter are either type constructors or data constructors, depending on whether you're looking at a type expression or a value expression). Since there is only one (non-bottom) value, the value tells you absolutely nothing (strictly speaking it does at least tell you that the computation did terminate successfully, but that's all). So `IO ()` is usually used as the type of IO actions that we're only interested in for their side-effects.

`putStrLn "Hello World"` is an example of a value of type `IO ()`. It doesn't compute anything at all interesting; what is the *value* resulting from having written a string to the terminal? Getting the `()` when it's executed only tells us that it did indeed execute.

`IO Int` is the type of an action that can be executed to extract a value of type `Int`. As with all IO actions, what exactly it does can have effects on and be affected by the world outside the program; Haskell knows nothing about them. But it does know that executing the action will result in a Haskell value of type `Int`, regardless of whatever else it might do.

`readLn :: IO Int` is an example of a value of type `IO Int` (the type annotation is necessary as a standalone expression to avoid ambiguity; in a wider context where you actually use the value extracted from `readLn` for some `Int`-specific operations you could probably leave it off). Unlike writing a string to the terminal, reading a string from the terminal and converting it to an `Int` *does* result in a value.

More generally `IO` is a type constructor that can be applied to any type; `IO a` is the type of an execution that could be executed and would result in a value of type `a`. Both of the above are just examples of this; neither is handled specially. `()` is a perfectly ordinary type, and `()` is a perfectly ordinary value of that type, but because such values don't convey any information (other than "this computation successfully terminated") you don't normally see `()` on its own; it tends to be used only with type constructors applied, such as in `IO ()`, for values where we care only about the structure added by the type constructor, not about the values "inside" it.